# Boost.Assign: using objects with map_list_of?

Tags: c++, boost, stdmap

Using C++ with boost.  In Boost.Assign can I use the new operator with map_list_of?

For example:

```
std::map<int, MyObject*> objects = boost::assign::map_list_of
       (1, new MyObject())(2, new MyObject())(3, new MyObject())
```

If not, is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems yes. This compiles fine with VS2010 & boost 1.47.

```
#include <boost\assign.hpp>
class MyObject{
public:
    MyObject(int i):m_i(i){}
private:
    int m_i;
};


int main (void)
{
    std::map<int, MyObject*> objects = boost::assign::map_list_of(1, new MyObject(1))(2, new MyObject(2))(3, new MyObject(3));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It does work, yes; calling new just returns a pointer to MyObject, and it can be used anywhere that type is valid. **HOWEVER** the call to new might throw an exception, or MyObject's constructor might throw an exception, meaning your whole map of heap-allocated MyObjects will be leaked.

If you want exception safety as well as not having to bother deleting those objects, you should use a smart pointer instead:

```
std::map<int, boost::shared_ptr<MyObject> > objects = boost::assign::map_list_of<int, boost::shared_ptr<MyObject> >
    (1, new MyObject())
    (2, new MyObject())
    (3, new MyObject());
```

Comment: This code is still not exception safe; the `MyObject*`s aren't turned into `shared_ptr<MyObject>`s until after `map_list_of` is done executing. In order to be exception safe, each `new MyObject()` would need to be replaced with e.g. `boost::make_shared<MyObject>()`.

Comment: @ildjarn you'd be absolutely right if map_list_of was a single function call; it's actually a functor object. map_list_of(1, new MyObject()); is its constructor, and is exception safe; each of the operator() invocations following is also exception safe.

Comment: @ildjarn on second thought, you're right here. map_list_of is going to deduce its second template parameter as being MyObject*, and will leak if an exception is thrown before it's finished. I've edited the template parameters of map_list_of so that it is exception safe.

Comment: Seriously, just call `make_shared` on those, instead.