# strange function in boost::assign::map_list_of

Tags: c++, boost, syntax

i find this construction:

```
std::map<T, T> a = boost::assign::map_list_of(arg11, arg12)
                                             (arg21, arg22)
                                             ;
```

Please, tell what happens in this and how to realize it on c++?

Comment: How to realize **what**?

Comment: Did you try looking at documentation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531878/boost-assign-using-objects-with-map-list-of

Comment: Of course! But this function takes one parameters, ok, but how this construction generate the map list? I don't know how it work. It's normal C++ construction?

Comment: The thread Chemistpp showed you, has all the details.... I want to point out and stress, this kind of initialization is just an alternate way boost provides of adding elements to a C++ map. Similar mechanism is used for filling other containers. You're are suppose to write less code if you use it correctly.

Comment: `Implementation-defined   map_list_of( Key k, T t )` has two parameters, and the type it returns has `Implementation-defined& operator()( U u, U2 u2 );`, which is also two parameters.

Comment: Are you using C++11? Before the C++11, boost library provided this initialization shortcuts, it helped you to write less code. In that sense it was no standard C++ construction. Here you can see how the map was traditionally initialized http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/

Comment: No, not C++11, but want to go in the future. Thanks.

Comment: chris, you right, i looked at list_of. But it does not change anything, cause list_of take a pair if it set in template argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't read the implementation, bu I think you can reproduce that with a "Accumulator" object :

```
template<class T>
class Acc
{
public:
   Acc &operator()(T a, T b)
   {
       map.insert(std::make_pair(a, b));
   }
   operator std::map<T, T>()
   {
       return map;
   }
 private:
   std::map<T, T> map;
}
```

Each time you do something like (a,b), you call the operator(), which just add the std::pair(a, b) inside the map. The cast operator allow to get a std::map instead of the Acc object.

The use is :

```
std::map<int, int> = Acc<int>()(1,2)(3,4)(6,7);
```

Nb : Code not tested.